# Matching values in variable length lists containing sublists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, sublist

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary where each key contains a list which in turn contains from 0 up to 20+ sub-lists. The goal is to iterate through the values of dictionary 1, check if they are in any of the sublists of dictionary 2 for the same key, and if so, add +1 to a counter and not consider that sublist again.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
dict1={"key1":[[1,2],[6,7]],"key2":[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]}
dict2={"key1":[[0,1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[11,13,15]],"key2":[[7,8,9,10,11],[16,17,18]]}

for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(dict1.iteritems(),dict2.iteritems()):
    temp_hold=[]
    span_overlap=0
    for x in v:
        if x in v2 and v2 not in temp_hold:
            span_overlap+=1
            temp_hold.append(v2)
        else:
            continue
    print temp_hold, span_overlap
```

This does obviously not work mainly due to the code not being able to check hierarchally through the list and sublists, and partly due to likely incorrect iteration syntax. I have not the greatest of grasp of nested loops and iterations which makes this a pain. Another option would be to first join the sublists into a single list using:

```
v=[y for x in v for y in x]
```

Which would make it easy to check if one value is in another dictionary, but then I lose the ability to work specifically with the sublist which contained parts of the values iterated through, nor can I count that sublist only once.

The desired output is a count of 2 for key1, and 1 for key2, as well as being able to handle the matching sublists for further analysis.

Comment: Should `dict1['key2']` be a list of lists in your example code?

Comment: Why is the output not a count of 4 for "key1": All four values in dict1 (1, 2,6,7) are in dict2['key1']. By the same reasoning, I would expect the count for "key1" to be 3. EDIT: I see that you only consider each sublist at most once.

Comment: what do you mean by check if they are in? do you mean matching sublists, all the elements of a sublist of dict1 are in and sublist of dict2?

Comment: @jme The value for key2 in dict1 should be a list in a list. The values are always a list, containing 0 to 20+ sublists. Edited

Comment: @Padraic The idea is to take each value of dict1, see if they are in any of the sublists in dict2 (for the same key) and if so, count +1, and remove that dict2 sublist from consideration again.

Comment: so you are comparing lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Comparing dictionary keys containing lists yes. I have about 6000 keys to look at.

Comment: It would seem, then, that the solution depends on the order in which you consider sublists. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: but you cannot have more than one of the same key so how could you check the same list twice?

Comment: @jme Not sure what behaviour I am expecting in that sense. That's the reason im here looking for insight into tackling this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. I am first converting the **list of lists** into a **list of sets**. If you have any control over the lists, make them sets.

```
def matching_sublists(dict1, dict2):
    result = dict()
    for k in dict1:
        assert(k in dict2)
        result[k] = 0
        A = [set(l) for l in dict1[k]]
        B = [set(l) for l in dict2[k]]
        for sublistA in A:
            result[k] += sum([1 for sublistB in B if not sublistA.isdisjoint(sublistB) ])
    return result


if __name__=='__main__':
    dict1={"key1":[[1,2],[6,7]],"key2":[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]}
    dict2={"key1":[[0,1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[11,13,15]],"key2":[[7,8,9,10,11],[16,17,18]]}
    print(matching_sublists(dict1, dict2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It outputs what I desire but would you mind explaining what happens at sum([1 for sublistB in B if not sublistA.isdisjoint(sublistB) ]) ?